# Error in using ingestion timestamp - Text '2022-04-23T10:15:07.024775Z' could not be parsed at index 20

Tags: java, date, elasticsearch

I am using the Ingest API to create a timestamp pipeline for an Elasticsearch document.

The format in which Elasticsearch gives the `{_ingest.timestamp}` is `2022-04-24T01:42:49.036897988Z`

Using Set Processor, I am adding the time of ingesting the documents, in the `@timestamp` field for all the documents, using

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/ts-pipeline
{
    "description": "Add timestamp field to all documents",
    "processors": [
        {
            "set": {
                "field": "timestamp",
                "value": "{{_ingest.timestamp}}"
            }
        },
        {
            "script": {
                "id":"calculate-timestamp"
            }
        },
        {
            "remove": {
                "field": "timestamp"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The definition of the script used above is given below. I need to convert the timestamp, to milliseconds, so for that, I followed this [discuss link](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/convert-timestamp-to-milliseconds-in-ingest-pipeline/294602/9)

```
POST _scripts/calculate-time
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "source": """DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS'Z'"); LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(ctx['timestamp'], dtf); ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of('Z')); ctx['@timestamp']=zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli();"""
  }
}
```

Mapping of `@timstamp` field is

```
"@timestamp": {
        "type": "date"
      }
```

But when indexing the documents, using this `@timestamp` field I get, the below error

> Text '2022-04-23T10:15:07.024775Z' could not be parsed at index 20

The issue is occurring since the format of ingestion time has changed from `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS'Z'` to `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z'`

**Can anyone please let me know, how come the format of the ingestion timestamp has changed to this format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z'`**

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: @Val I am using Java 17 version, and Elasticsearch 8.1.3